# Populate Angular form with data passed by another app

Tags: angular, spring-boot

I am new to angular and following is my requirement, not sure how I can do it in Angular.

My Angular app will receive HTTP POST data as json from another application (we cant change that method from POST to GET)

I have to show a pre-filled form in Angular app using json data received from different apps.

I am also using springboot. I do not use any database ( so cant store data and call service from angular.

Comment: What's your question exactly? Any code snippet of your issue? What about the response from API?

Comment: More details please! Are you using template driven forms, or reactive forms in Angular?

Comment: If the POST is returning data you can consume it just like you would a GET.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a post endpoint on your service that stores the data serverside somehow and then redirects to the Angular app. Then you have another endpoint on your service that the Angular app can retrieve that data from.

Angular is a client side application and cannot be the action of a post.

Comment: Adrian, I do not have any database to store info

Comment: What is in the payload of the post? You might be able to JSON.stringify it and pass it to Angular on a route param or querystring.

Comment: Problem with that is URL has character limit

Comment: Then you need a serverside solution.

Comment: Are you pointing to use Node.js? Any examples would be great.

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved this by using spring-boot session.Hope if it helps someone.

HTML CODE

```
<form method="post" id="complainForm" action="http://localhost:8882/aalcomplaint/api/complaint/lodge-complaint" target="_blank">
  <!-- you can build your own json string as you like-->
  <input type="hidden" name="complainData" value='{"policyNumber":"1234", "firstName":"aa" , "lastName" : "mm"}' />
  <input type="submit" id="LodgeComplain" name="LodgeComplain" value="Lodge Complain"/>
</form>
```

SPRING BOOT CODE

```
@Slf4j
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
@RestController
@TamAuthentication
public class ComplainsController {

  @PostMapping(value = "/aalcomplaint/api/complaint/lodge-complaint")
  public ModelAndView lodgeComplaint(@RequestBody String complainData, ModelAndView modelAndView, final HttpServletRequest request) {

    final String id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    try {
      final ComplaintDto complaintDto = convertRequestDataToObject(complainData);
      request.getSession().setAttribute(id, complaintDto);
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
      log.error(e.getMessage());
    }
    modelAndView.setViewName("redirect:/#/lodge-complain?id=" + id);
    return modelAndView;
  }

  @GetMapping(value = "/aalcomplaint/api/complaint/get-data/{id}")
  public ComplaintDto getData(@PathVariable String id, final HttpServletRequest request) {
    //TODO: id not null & empty check
    final ComplaintDto complaintDto = (ComplaintDto) request.getSession().getAttribute(id);
    request.getSession().removeAttribute(id);
    return complaintDto;
  }

  private ComplaintDto convertRequestDataToObject(String complainData) throws IOException {
    final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    complainData = URLDecoder.decode(complainData, "UTF-8");
    log.info("complainData > " + complainData);
    return mapper.readValue(complainData.split("=")[1], ComplaintDto.class);
  }



}
```

ANGULAR CODE

```
export class LodgeComplainComponent {

  complainDto: ComplainDto;
  id : string;

  constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, private http: HttpClient, private refService: RefService) {
    this.complainDto = new ComplainDto();

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
      this.id =  params['id'];
      console.log('id - ' + params['id']);        
    });

    this.refService.getData(this.id).subscribe(result => {
            this.complainDto = result;
    });
  }
}
```